# Seaborn JointGrid: Separated bar lines on histogram, removing trendline, removing curve over histogram

Tags: python, image-processing, matplotlib, seaborn

This is the outputted image in a Seaborn JointPlot
[image]

I want to do three things to get it to show like 
[image: Expected outcome]

1. Remove the Trend line on the scatter portion
2. Show distinct demarcations of bars on the histogram plot
3. Remove the curves on the histogram plots.

Adding 'edgecolor' only demarcates the circles on the scatter plot, not the histogram.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. **We are here to help in your code**, if you haven't tried anything then we cant help much. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of SO and read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to see how to ask a question. Can you paste the full code for someone to have a look or do you want the bar removed from the image?

Answer (score 3):

> Remove the Trend line on the scatter portion +  Remove the curves on the
>   histogram plots.

These can be done by removing the `kind='reg'` argument you have on `.jointplot`.

> Show distinct demarcations of bars on the histogram plot

Access the `hist_kws` inside `marginal_kws` and change `edgecolor` attribute, an example with sample data:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.jointplot("total_bill", "tip", data=tips, marginal_kws={'hist_kws': {'edgecolor': "black"}})
plt.show()
```

---

[image]